# How to call user defined function on click in modal (bootstrap 4) in angular 7

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular7

I am doing function call using bootstrap 4 modal in angular 7, when i trying to call function from template to ts not performing anything. In modal function call not working on click without using Jquery.

**Template :**

```
<button type="button" class="call-end" (click)="muteVideoCall()">
        <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
     </button>
```

**TS:**

```
public muteVideoCall() {

  }
```

when I trying to call fuction on click from template it will working

Comment: Try to give us a screenshot of what event listeners are attached to the button

Comment: I don't see any reason why it won't work. Please reproduce the issue so that correct problem can be found.

Comment: on mouse click event listener on modal call to muteVideoCall() function in .ts file @Arcteezy

Comment: Yeah I got that. The code you provide will work fine. The error is something else and can only be understood if you provide a demo. Please try to reproduce the issue in stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="videoModelExp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog full_modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content-videocall full_modal-content">
                    <div class="internaldiv">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 local-img-border">
                          <video #video1 muted="muted" autoplay>
                            <source>
                          </video>
                          <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-12 text-right icon-center">
                                <button type="button"class="call-start">
                                  <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="call-end" (click)="muteVideoCall()">
                                  <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="screen-share" (click)="enableScreen()" data-toggle="modal"
                                  data-target="#screenshareModelExp">
                                  <i class="fa fa-window-restore" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
              </div>
           </div>
         </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I didn't added the **class="modal-content"** so i doesn't performing the click event :) now it is working fine after adding model-content

Comment: <div class="modal-content modal-content-videocall full_modal-content"> </div>